# Wordpress meta query: searching for number value smaller or higher not working?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post field that store number like: 1,2,3 and so on.
I use Toolset to generate the custom post and field.
I want to display all the custom post that have this number value smaller then let's say 2, here is my query, but Wordpress doesn't display the correct post:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'video',
        'posts_per_page'    => 1,
        'no_found_rows'     => true,
        'meta_query'        => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'wpcf-number',
                'value' => 2,
                'meta_compare' => '<',
                'type' => 'UNSIGNED'
            )
        )
    );

    $latest_interview = new WP_Query($args);

    echo $latest_interview->request;
```

This is how the generated SQL appears:

```
SELECT wpasdasdasd_posts.ID 
FROM wpasdasdasd_posts 
INNER JOIN wpasdasdasd_postmeta ON ( wpasdasdasd_posts.ID = wpasdasdasd_postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( ( wpasdasdasd_postmeta.meta_key = 'wpcf-number' AND CAST(wpasdasdasd_postmeta.meta_value AS UNSIGNED) = '2' ) ) 
AND wpasdasdasd_posts.post_type = 'video' 
AND (wpasdasdasd_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wpasdasdasd_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY wpasdasdasd_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wpasdasdasd_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Note that the `CAST(mt1.meta_value AS UNSIGNED) = '2' )`
is not set to `< '2'`
which seems to me like the logical thing.
And Wordpress doesn't display what I'm looking for: just one video that has a number smaller then 2.
Running Wordpress 5.4
Is there something that I'm doing wrong here ? Thanks !

Comment: `meta_query` has no key `meta_compare`. replace it with `compare`

Comment: thanks ! This is it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use "compare" key instead of "meta_compare". Try like this:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'video',
        'posts_per_page'    => 1,
        'no_found_rows'     => true,
        'meta_query'        => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'wpcf-number',
                'value' => 2,
                'compare' => '<',
                'type' => 'UNSIGNED'
            )
        )
    );

    $latest_interview = new WP_Query($args);

    echo $latest_interview->request;
```